# Prove that $f$ is a constant complex function.

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, maximum-principle

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

> [image]

Here is a trial for the solution that I do not really follow it:

> [image]
> [image]

Is the trial of the solution above correct? what are the sequence of ideas required to solve this problem? Are there any more elegant and succinct solution? what is the general idea that should be used in proving that a certain complex function is constant?

Comment: It looks fine. I missed the definition of the $c$ that they subtract in $h(z):=g(z)-c$, but one can guess from the context that it is the value of $f$ on the unit circle.

Comment: The above solution looks very complex, so to speak.

Comment: @copper.hat I agree ..... I could not capture what actually the author is doing and why

Comment: @user85667 what was the importance of creating the sequence? we already know $f(z)$ is bounded, right?

Comment: Well, they included the proof that finite $\limsup$ implies bounded, that's all. The sequence is to prove this. Note that the value of the $\limsup$ is not an upper bound. The function can be larger than the value of the $\limsup$ at many points.

Comment: @user85667 also the statement of Riemann theorem that I know does not conclude that we have a removable singularity of $f,$ right? I am using a book named "complex variables with applications" by S. Ponnusamy and Herb Silverman

Comment: As far as I understand, the limit of the function is always less than or equal the limit sup of the function ..... right?@user85667

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\lim_{z \to 0} z f(z) = 0$ we see that $f$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, so we may assume $f$ is analytic on $D$.

Let $c=f(z)$ for $|z|=1$.
Suppose $z_0 \in D$ and let $|z_0|<r<1$ and $\gamma_r(t) = r e^{it}$, then
$f(z_0) = {1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma_r} {f(z) \over z-z_0} dz$. Taking
the limit $r \to 1$ we get $f(z_0) = c$.

**Elaboration**:

$f(z_0) = {1 \over 2 \pi } \int_0^{2 \pi} {f(r e^{it}) \over re^{it}-z_0} r e^{it} dt$. Note that the function $z \mapsto z{f(z) \over z-z_0}$ is uniformly continuous on the compact
$\{ z | \rho \le |z| \le 1 \}$, where $\rho$ is some number in $(|z_0|,1)$. It follows that
$\lim_{r \uparrow 1} {1 \over 2 \pi } \int_0^{2 \pi} {f(r e^{it}) \over re^{it}-z_0} r e^{it} dt= {1 \over 2 \pi } \int_0^{2 \pi} {f(e^{it}) \over e^{it}-z_0} r e^{it} dt  = c{1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_{\gamma_1} {1 \over z-z_0} dz = c$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138661/discussion-on-answer-by-copper-hat-prove-that-f-is-a-constant-complex-function).